# Annotating screen recording done with QuickTime?

Tags: macos, video, annotations, screen-recorder

I have done a couple of screen recordings that I am currently touching up. I have done them using the built-in QuickTime screen recording function.

Now I would like to create text annotations, like balloons or text boxes pointing to different regions in the recording. QuickTime does not seem to have this functionality, and while I can do it with iMovie, it is way to clumsy for me to feel comfortable using. For example, it requires me to convert the whole clip (a process taking minutes on a fairly recent MBP). And it also does not seem to keep the native resolution and sharpness of the recording.

I tried browsing the app store and there are lots of screen recording / screenshot tools, but I could not find any "video annotation" tool.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only tool that I've used for that is [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) for OS X – typical screencast recording software. It has a 30 day full-featured trial version, so you can try if it fits your needs and I guess it won't complain if you never close it.

It offers all kinds of annotation tools, including:

- Text
- Arrows
- Rectangles
- Blurring
- Highlighting

Drag and drop your existing videos to the app and you can use them without converting. You can keep the native  resolution of your input recordings, and export is very fast. Editing can be done with multiple video and audio tracks as well as transitions etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That looks good. I was hoping I didn't have to re-record my sessions though, do you know if it is possible to import existing videos?

Comment: Sure, just drag and drop them into the app!